# How to use sbt behind authenticated proxy?

Tags: scala, proxy, sbt

As given in other answers. I have properly set the value of http proxy host and port.
but it is giving the following error

```
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.6 ...
```

You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
    Host repo.typesafe.com not found. url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.6/ivys/ivy.xml

```
Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.6/sbt-0.13.6.pom

Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.6/sbt-0.13.6.jar

    module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.6

==== local: tried

  /home/vibhanshu/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.6/ivys/ivy.xml

  -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.6!sbt.jar:

  /home/vibhanshu/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.6/jars/sbt.jar

==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

  https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.6/ivys/ivy.xml

==== Maven Central: tried

  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.6/sbt-0.13.6.pom

  -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.6!sbt.jar:

  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.6/sbt-0.13.6.jar

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.6: not found

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.6: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see /home/vibhanshu/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in behind the proxy(corporate network)
For windows :

In sbt installation folder, go to conf/sbtconfig.txt file just add the following lines and save and try.

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy
-Dhttp.proxyPort=portno
-Dhttp.proxyUser=UserId
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=Password

-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyhost
-Dhttps.proxyPort=portno 
-Dhttps.proxyUser=UserId
-Dhttps.proxyPassword=Password
```

For Linux/Unix:

```
 export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyHost  -Dhttp.proxyPort=proxyPortNumber -Dhttp.proxyUser=UserId -Dhttp.proxyPassword=Password -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyHost -Dhttps.proxyPort=proxyPortNumber  -Dhttps.proxyUser=UserId -Dhttps.proxyPassword=Password"
```

It worked for me too.

Answer (score 6):

I added the following line to .bashrc.

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=port -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy -Dhttps.proxyPort=port"
```

It works fine.

Comment: i run this command before run sbt in windows- set JAVA_OPTS="%JAVA_OPTS% -Dhttp.proxyHost=**** -Dhttp.proxyPort= -Dhttp.proxyUser= -Dhttp.proxyPassword="  ...still i get below error: set JAVA_OPTS="%JAVA_OPTS% -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy-******** -Dhttp.proxyPort=****-Dhttp.proxyUser=***** -Dhttp.proxyPassword=****"

Comment: Worked perfectly for me on Ubuntu, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue (behind corporate firewall and getting this error message) and I tried all the options from various related threads but none of them resolved the problem. I was able to finally get IntelliJ to work by configuring HTTP Proxy in IntelliJ itself. Here's what my configurations look like (Note: provide your network username and password in related boxes):-

[image]