# stuck at "Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.6 ..." when running sbt in terminal

Tags: java, sbt

Similar problem with [How to use sbt behind authenticated proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582300/how-to-use-sbt-behind-authenticated-proxy). I tried with the given answer and problem still there.

When I run **sbt** in terminal, it shows and stucks at :

```
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.6 ...
```

additional information:

```
 sbt --version
 sbt launcher version 0.13.6
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: what's your connectivity? proxy?

Comment: no, proxy is ok. I add build.properties under project folder. it then works. @Mysterion thanks for the reply.

Comment: please, add it as an answer to question.

Comment: This should be fixed in sbt 1.0, by the way. We've experienced instant downloads (less than 17 seconds for the whole sbt universe) of sbt 1.0 after several improvements in the librarymanagement side.

Comment: I am on sbt 1.8.2, and this happened to me. Stuck for hours, no progress, overnight. It turned out that sbt has some dependency that shells out to PowerShell, and the PowerShell process was locking up. You have to find sbt's child PowerShell process and kill it, and then sbt will continue. Related info -- https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5128

Answer (score 218):

This is quite old post and my answer may not be completely relevant. But here is my experience:

1. I am using sbt 0.13.8
2. Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.8 ...
3. I have got this line hanging for some time - between 5 to 10
   minutes.
4. And then it started to download stuff.

**So my solution is that you have to wait a bit.**

Comment: Thanks! I was "waiting" while looking up the problem and reading this page. Now I checked the window again, and it's downloading all the jars... *sloooowwwlllyyyy* `:)`

Comment: Running sbt in verbose mode helped me determine that there were some downloads happening that just weren't visible to me, e.g., `$ sbt -v`

Comment: If you're here, like me, you probably have a slow internet connection :)

Comment: You can also try to hit "Enter" after couple of minutes :) In my case - it instantly started to download jars.

Comment: Sometimes sbt stuck when downloading files. You can periodically check size ~/.ivy2 folder and if size isn't grow kick sbt process and rerun sbt.
For my only after 5 kicks sbt download all files!!!

Comment: Waiting...kale.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I did the same approach. Slowly and steadly getting downloaded!! :)

Comment: Stuck over 20 minutes on my Mac... `:(` Just have to wait

Comment: It turns out that repo.typesafe.com is sometimes really slow. You just have to wait I guess.

Answer (score 49):

There is an update log ...

```
$ tail -f $HOME/.sbt/boot/update.log
```

Execute the above command in another terminal to see the progress.
Using -v option works as others already indicated as well.

Comment: thanks that helped.   20 minutes later ... i was worried.   for some reason repo.typesafe.com is tremendously slow

Answer (score 13):

I bypassed the error by adding a build.properties file under project folder, in which, I put:

```
  sbt.version=0.13.5
```

I think this probably is because my system has activator pre-installed instead of sbt, which is easier to work with play project. Not quite clear in the theory as I just start to use sbt.

Comment: Worked for sbt 0.13.8 too!

Comment: It worked for me too. The project declared in the project/build.properties file that it required 0.13.8 and the command was getting stuck trying to get it. Changing the declaration to 0.13.7 fixed it.

Comment: I think this works only if you already have the specified version (0.13.5, in this case) of sbt downloaded. For example, I have ~/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.4/org.scala-sbt/sb/0.13.1 and ~/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.5/org.scala-sbt/sb/0.13.9, and my sbt program is sbt-0.13.13.1-1.noarch, sbt will not try "Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.13 ..." if a set sbt.version=0.13.1 or sbt.version=0.13.9. 

It's also possible to set sbt version with CLI options:

  # sbt version (default: from project/build.properties if present, else latest release)
  -sbt-version  <version>   use the specified version of sbt

Comment: At least I am able to see logs being printed. After 10 minutes or so it started to download.

Answer (score 12):

It is downloading things, just use `$ sbt -v`, it will show **logs**.

Comment: `sbt -v` is better than `tail -f $HOME/.sbt/boot/update.log` sometimes, when `sbt -v` log something while the other not.

Comment: nope it is doing nothing in my case

Answer (score 9):

I think sbt takes some time to download its jars when it is run first time. That is why it seems to be stuck. It works normal after the download is completed.

Answer (score 4):

It's quite a late answer, but I encountered the same problem working behind a proxy. If this is your case, you should run `export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS
-Dhttp.proxyHost=<your-proxy> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<your-proxy-port>"` before running `sbt`.

If you are still unsure if it's going ahead with the downloading, you should try launching `sbt` with the verbose option `sbt -v`, as suggested by @evan912. If you had a problem with the proxy, after setting it you should see some `[info] downloading` logging on your console.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a build.sbt file worked as well. My build.sbt file looks like below;

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "hello",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.4"
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem of sbt getting stuck on "***getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.4.7  (this may take some time)...***". I resolved this problem by commenting the $JAVA_HOME variable in bashrc, and restarting the terminal. You can also ensure that the JAVA_HOME is not set by running `echo $JAVA_HOME`. Subsequently, rerun the sbt command with `-v` flag (for verbosity). After running the command, you should observe prints after "*getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.4.7  (this may take some time)...*" line.

Answer (score -3):

try to use a fast maven mirror or run it behind a http/https proxy .