# Upgraded to sbt 0.13.9; now I cannot launch sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I upgraded sbt from version 0.13.8 to 0.13.9. We have Nexus proxying many repositories. Now, when I issue 'sbt' command - I get unresolved dependencies

```
scala-library
scala-compilre
scala-reflect
```

all due to sha1 different from the computed. Is there a way to bypass sha1 validation?
FYI. setting `checksums in update := Nil` in `build.sbt` does not solve the problem. I even tried putting
`<property name="ivy.checksums" value=""/>` in `~/.ivy/ivysettings.xml` still fails.

here is the console output:

```
D:\Temp\test>sbt -v update
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.9 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        problem while downloading module descriptor: http://nexusserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/mvn-repositories/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.5/scala-library-2.10.5.pom: invalid sha1: expected=c39e31e37ce77d8d5fb8e8c640222275815d36f2 computed=4e8b721680f2defb491fe90447302658d464d5c
0 (351ms)

                module not found: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.5

        ==== local: tried

          C:\Users\ak\.ivy2\local\org.scala-lang\scala-library\2.10.5\ivys\ivy.xml

          -- artifact org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.5!scala-library.jar:

          C:\Users\ak\.ivy2\local\org.scala-lang\scala-library\2.10.5\jars\scala-library.jar

        ==== my-ivy-proxy-releases: tried

          http://nexusserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/ivy-releases/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.5/ivys/ivy.xml

        ==== my-maven-proxy-releases: tried

          http://nexusserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/mvn-repositories/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.5/scala-library-2.10.5.pom

        problem while downloading module descriptor: http://nexusserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/mvn-repositories/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.5/scala-compiler-2.10.5.pom: invalid sha1: expected=9a85822af1f9ea46b49dfdfa99eafc0bd819abaf computed=c3e0b6cf2f45a5a7cb052ef9e00f8fdac55e7
1b7 (69ms)

                module not found: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.5

        ==== local: tried

          C:\Users\ak\.ivy2\local\org.scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.10.5\ivys\ivy.xml

          -- artifact org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.5!scala-compiler.jar:

          C:\Users\ak\.ivy2\local\org.scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.10.5\jars\scala-compiler.jar

        ==== my-ivy-proxy-releases: tried

          http://nexusserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/ivy-releases/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.5/ivys/ivy.xml

        ==== my-maven-proxy-releases: tried

          http://nexusserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/mvn-repositories/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.5/scala-compiler-2.10.5.pom

        problem while downloading module descriptor: http://nexusserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/mvn-repositories/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.10.5/scala-reflect-2.10.5.pom: invalid sha1: expected=3a6fa11041ac0c8b4d5fcf9d4f1372ba8c0b7216 computed=30f1f646114a79eeefb254ead190f045c460564
9 (67ms)

                module not found: org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.5

        ==== local: tried

          C:\Users\ak\.ivy2\local\org.scala-lang\scala-reflect\2.10.5\ivys\ivy.xml

          -- artifact org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.5!scala-reflect.jar:

          C:\Users\ak\.ivy2\local\org.scala-lang\scala-reflect\2.10.5\jars\scala-reflect.jar

        ==== my-ivy-proxy-releases: tried

          http://nexusserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/ivy-releases/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.10.5/ivys/ivy.xml

        ==== my-maven-proxy-releases: tried

          http://nexusserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/mvn-repositories/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.10.5/scala-reflect-2.10.5.pom

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.5: not found

                :: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.5: not found

                :: org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.5: not found

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.5: not found
unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.5: not found
unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.5: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see C:\Users\ak\.sbt\boot\update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.9
```

Comment: have you tried to clean your ivy2-cache? I think the default `externalResolvers` have changed in 0.13.9

Comment: I did. I deleted 'cache' directory.

Comment: what about your projects target and plugins target folders?

Comment: what scala version? I just tried and works fine for sbt 0.13.9 and `scalaVersion := 2.11.7`

Comment: I have exactly same version in my sbt file, but sbt itself is not starting up because of the internal dependencies. I think it fails before the processing of my build.sbt

Comment: Well, as asked before have you deleted `<your-project>/project/target`?

Comment: Yes, I have. Still getting the same error. It looks like it's failing during the bootstrapping itself.

Comment: Well, clean everything again, run sbt in verbose mode `sbt -v update` and give us the output. Maybe, it will help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87522/discussion-between-alex-khvatov-and-sascha-kolberg).

Comment: sorry, was in bed ;) The issue seems to be in your nexus proxy. You might need to reconfigure your sbt plugin repositories. But I do not have any experience with *Sonatype Nexus*.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that route.

Comment: Waiting worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31712249/1433665

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be an ordering issue with our Nexus proxy repositories. oss.sonatype.org maven repo was causing an issue when it was placed ahead of the Maven Central repo. Removing oss.sonatype.org maven repository solved the problem.

Comment: Hit that problem, too. sonatype-oss seems to still have problems with wrong hashes :-/